# Image rectification using Flow vs SURF

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0, multiview, stereoscopy

I am trying something with the multiview and stereo from motion but I faced an issue that I can't explain or make to work properly.

I used two differents methods for keypoints extraction on two images (**[SURF](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_surf_intro/py_surf_intro.html) or [flow](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_lucas_kanade.html) **), and when I draw the rectified images side by side the two methods are way too much different, and it seems that *the optical flow* technique is not working well for rectification.

(Left: SURF, Right: Optical flow) Ransac parameter (0.1, 0.99):

[image: Using SURF]
[image: Using FLOW]

Here you can see part of the code I use to rectify and draw the images : (I got inspired a lot by [Michael Beleyer's book](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/opencv-python-blueprints))

```
    self.matcher.extract_keypoints(use_flow=use_flow)
    self.matcher.set_fundamental_matrix()
    self.matcher.set_essential_matrix()
    self.matcher.find_camera_matrices()

    R = self.matcher.Rt2[:, :3]
    T = self.matcher.Rt2[:, 3]

    R1, R2, P1, P2, Q, roi1, roi2 = cv2.stereoRectify(self.matcher.K, self.matcher.d,
                                                      self.matcher.K, self.matcher.d,
                                                      self.matcher.image1.image.shape[:2],
                                                      R, T, alpha=1.0)

    mapx1, mapy1 = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(self.matcher.K, self.matcher.d, R1, self.matcher.K,
                                               self.matcher.image1.image.shape[:2],
                                               cv2.CV_32F)
    mapx2, mapy2 = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(self.matcher.K, self.matcher.d, R2, self.matcher.K,
                                               self.matcher.image2.image.shape[:2],
                                               cv2.CV_32F)

    rectified1 = cv2.remap(self.matcher.image1.image, mapx1, mapy1, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    rectified2 = cv2.remap(self.matcher.image2.image, mapx2, mapy2, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

    # draw the images side by side
    total_size = (max(rectified1.shape[0], rectified2.shape[0]),
                  rectified1.shape[1] + rectified2.shape[1], 3)
    stacked_images = np.zeros(total_size, dtype=np.uint8)
    stacked_images[:rectified1.shape[0], :rectified1.shape[1]] = rectified1
    stacked_images[:rectified2.shape[0], rectified1.shape[1]:] = rectified2

    # draw horizontal lines every 25 px accross the side by side image
    for i in range(20, stacked_images.shape[0], 25):
        cv2.line(stacked_images, (0, i), (stacked_images.shape[1], i), (255, 0, 0))

    cv2.imshow('Rectified Image', stacked_images)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

Can someone explain to me why there is such a difference between the two and why there is so much black in the pictures ?

**QEdit**: Why is there so much black in the pictures ? And why does the Ransac parameters change the result this much ? And we need to change them depending on the algorithm used later ?

**EDIT**: I found that my Ransac algorithm parameters for fundamental matrix calculation (0.1-0.99) is too wide and catch too much unwanted outliers. (I am not sure so an explanation is welcome here too)

And here is what I get (Left: SURF, Right: Optical flow) Ransac parameter (1, 0.99):

[image: Using SURF (1-0.99)]
[image: With flow (1-0.99)]